# List<int[]> is populated only by last contents of int[]

Tags: c#, list, int

I am testing how to get multiple data returned from a function. I was trying to use a List of `int[]`. To do this I have a function that returns a `List<int[]>`, which is shown below:

```
private List<int[]> Test()
{
        List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();
        int[] record = new int[3];
        record[0] = 1;
        record[1] = 2;
        record[2] = 3;
        testlist.Add(record);
        record[0] = 11;
        record[1] = 12;
        record[2] = 13;
        testlist.Add(record);
        return testlist;
}
```

When i check the contents of the list, I see that it contains 2 records but they both contain the last records of the `int[]`. Which means that instead of

```
list[0] = {1,2,3}
list[1] = {11,12,13}
```

I get

```
list[0] = {11,12,13}
list[1] = {11,12,13}
```

I was wondering why this is happening.

Comment: Arrays are reference types. You add the same reference twice to the list, then you modify it.  You have to create a new array instead.

Comment: You are adding the same array to both elements. Create a new array for each element.

Comment: You need to do `record = new int[3];` after `testlist.Add(record);`

Comment: You need to create another array after adding first record. i.e add this line again `record = new int[3];` after first `testlist.Add(record)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Related question, Not  duplicated question.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the extremely fast and spot-on responses! The further reading links are very useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one instance of `int[] record` which you place twice into your list. An array is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). The documentation states:

> With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable.

In the second run you overwrite the values of the first one, because `record` still refers to the same object. This is why you have the same values in both arrays.

To solve it you need to create a brand new instance for every entry in the list:

```
 private List<int[]> Test()
{
    List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();
    int[] record = new int[3];
    record[0] = 1;
    record[1] = 2;
    record[2] = 3;
    testlist.Add(record);

    int[] record2 = new int[3];
    record2[0] = 11;
    record2[1] = 12;
    record2[2] = 13;
    testlist.Add(record2);
    return testlist;
}
```

For more information on Reference and Value-Types please read [this article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Because you have override the reference and add that into the list**. if you assign the values into a new reference then you can get what you want.

try this

```
 private List<int[]> Test()
{
        List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();
        int[] record = new int[3];
        record[0] = 1;
        record[1] = 2;
        record[2] = 3;
        testlist.Add(record);
        record = new int[3];// create new reference
        record[0] = 11;
        record[1] = 12;
        record[2] = 13;
        testlist.Add(record);
        return testlist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`testlist.Add(record)` is adding a *reference* to `record` to the `testlist` array.

In other words, you aren't adding two separate arrays to `testlist`; you're adding a reference to the same array, `record`, twice.

This means that, if you modify `record` after adding it to the list, it updates inside the list too. `testlist` doesn't contain 'actual arrays', it contains a *pointer* to an array. In this case, that pointer is to `record`.

You could fix this by introducing a new array:

```
 private List<int[]> Test()
{
        List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();
        int[] record = new int[3];
        record[0] = 1;
        record[1] = 2;
        record[2] = 3;
        testlist.Add(record);
        int[] record2 = new int[3];
        record2[0] = 11;
        record2[1] = 12;
        record2[2] = 13;
        testlist.Add(record2);
        return testlist;
}
```

Then your list contains two *different* objects, rather than two references to the same one.

To learn more about this, you should Google and read about *pass-by-reference* and *pass-by-value*. C# uses pass-by-reference for most function parameters, with the notable exceptions being basic numeric types (e.g. `int` and `float`) and structs.

Comment: @MongZhu Whoops, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, e.g. `int[]` are reference types.
So when you assign `11` to the first cell of the array, you are overwriting the `1` that was originally in this cell. Because your `List<int[]>` only holds a reference to the array, the value is changed there as well.

Instead, assign a copy of the array to the list to break these references:

```
List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();

int[] record = new int[3];
record[0] = 1;
record[1] = 2;
record[2] = 3;
testlist.Add(record.ToArray()); // LINQ ToArray will create a copy

record[0] = 11;
record[1] = 12;
record[2] = 13;
testlist.Add(record.ToArray()); // LINQ ToArray will create a copy

return testlist;
```

Or do not reuse the same array:

```
List<int[]> testlist = new List<int[]>();
int[] record1 = new int[3];
record1[0] = 1;
record1[1] = 2;
record1[2] = 3;
testlist.Add(record1);

int[] record2 = new int[3];
record2[0] = 11;
record2[1] = 12;
record2[2] = 13;
testlist.Add(record2);

return testlist;
```

Further reading: [Difference between a Value Type and a Reference Type](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)